# Date formatting differently in the same Telerik Kendo UI Grid

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been using Kendo grids all over my MVC3 project without issue. However recently I added some Ajax only MVC razor grids with 3 date columns. Although the dates are formatted exactly the same, one of the columns just refuses to be recognised as a date and does not format.

I have tried with the Microsoft json date format, then wrote my own JsonNetResult class for formatting the dates in ISO 8601 format and then finally I altered this to produce the dates format show below below 'yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'. None of these formats allow me to reformat the date for the 'Uploaded Date' column!! The other two columns are recognised as dates and format accordingly.

The c# model (additional props removed for brevity) looks like:

```cs
public class EmailAuditListModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Investor's alert sent")]
    public DateTime? InvestorSent { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Adviser's alert sent")]
    public DateTime? AdviserSent { get; set; }

    public virtual DocumentListModel Document { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentListModel
{
    [DisplayName("DocId")]
    public int DocId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Uploaded Date")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON is a collection in the following format (extra fields removed). You can see the dates are all consistent.

```js
{
  "Date": "2015-03-27 17:56:37",
  "InvestorSent": "2015-03-27 17:56:39",
  "AdviserSent": "2015-03-27 17:56:36",
  "Document": {
    "UploadDate": "2015-03-27 17:42:49"
  }
}
```

The Razor view code (with extra fields removed) is:

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmailAuditListModel>()
          .Name("EmailAuditGrid")
          .Columns(columns => 
          {
              columns.Bound(e => e.InvestorSent).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}").Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.AdviserSent).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}").Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(e => e.Document.UploadDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}");
          })
          .Groupable()
          .Sortable()
          .Filterable()
          .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
          .Pageable(pageable => pageable
              .Refresh(true)
              .PageSizes(true)
              .ButtonCount(5))
          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
              .Ajax()
              .Read(read => read.Action("EmailAudits_Read","Document"))
              .Sort(sort => sort.Add(e => e.Document.UploadDate).Descending()))
          .ColumnMenu()
          )
```

...and the grid looks like

[image: Screenshot of grid showing 3 date columns]

Any ideas??

Comment: Easy guess, it because your data in "UploadDate" property is a string..

Comment: Please post your model.

Comment: @Vash I have added the model to the question for you.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: I try with your with your given data, Kendo-Grid format date as per the format given. see http://plnkr.co/edit/w9RYyOAMc0IGf9W3e6b9?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the upload date is coming out different is due to being recognised as a string type rather than a date type. This unfortunately is a limitation of the DataSource object that is being bound to the grid. In order to get the date formatting correctly you can try one of the following:

1) put the date at the root level of the model object (as per @suvroc's) post which is fine but means you are then having to alter your model's to work with the front end.

2) Provide a string formatted version of the Date in your sub model like so:

```
public class DocumentListModel
{
    [DisplayName("DocId")]
    public int DocId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Uploaded Date")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Uploaded Date")]
    public string UploadDateToString 
    {
        get
        { 
            return UploadDate.toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your grid binding for this property from the current uploaded one.

3) Use the inbuilt client templating to reformat the column like so:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Document.UploadDate)
.ClientTemplate("#=reformatDateTime(data.Document.UploadDate,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')#");
```

Then using a javascript function like this:

```
function reformatDateTime(dateValue, dateFormat){
     return kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(dateValue), dateFormat); 
}
```

What this will do is convert the date value in a valid date object and then format it based on the date format you pass in.

I personally prefer option 3 myself as it is simpler and more maintainable and once it is written it can be reused everywhere.

Well I hope this helps and if you need any more info give me a shout.

Comment: Great complete answer, thanks. I guess the long and short of it, is that the Kendo grid is not geared for nested objects! Your 3rd answer is the easiest to implement, but if you are using filters in the column menus, as it's still not recognized by the grid as a DateTime, the calendar filter does not appear. Flattened ViewModels is the best approach from if done at the start! Thanks

Comment: Using nested objects you can get the filtering working by implementing your own filter to deal with this scenario but Telerik do advise that you use a flatten ViewModel where possible (I experienced the same issue a few months back so got in touch with Telerik's support which is why I suggested the possible solutions)

Answer (score 2):

My first approach to this problem is to flatten your model before you pass it to Kendo Grid configuration.

```
public class EmailAuditListModelFlat
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InvestorSent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AdviserSent { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocumentUploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

PS. Probably it should be a comment, but I can't write it yet

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right in my case, but flagged other answer as best as this give details of all alternative options. Much appreciated though.